# How does linux protect memory?

Tags: linux, memory-management, assembly, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm interested in how linux runs in protected mode from an assembly point of view. Which registers and interrupts are used when it comes to putting the cpu in protected mode for an i386:0x86_64 machine? I understand how memory managment works when I look at the c source of functions like mmap and mprotect, however whats keeping me from taking over with assembly? Where can I get more info on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`arch/x86/mm/`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.2/arch/x86/mm/) -- [`arch/x86/mm/init.c`](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.3.2/arch/x86/mm/init.c) sets up the page tables for the correct architecture (ia32 or AMD64) and takes into account the processor features available (PSE, PGE, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It bears stressing: This is a function of the processor.  Linux tells the processor what to protect, and the processor does it.

AFA the system call interface, have a glance at http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/pbmonherc.html from back before the C library had mmap, but after the Linux kernel did.  See file mmap.c.